# fetch data from ndb query by KeyProperty field

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have User model and another model is user token

```
 class User(EndpointsModel):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

    @classmethod
    def get_by_name(cls,name)
         return cls.query(cls.name == name).get()
```

2 model is user token

```
 class Token(EndpointsModel):
    user = ndb.KeyProperty()
    token = ndb.StringProperty()

    @classmethod
    def get_by_user(cls, key):
        return   cls.query(cls.token == key).get()
```

Now i fetch data from user

```
  data = User.get_by_name('jaskaran')
```

when i try to fetch token then it return me None

```
 print( Token.get_by_user(data.key) )
```

this is return None How can i fetch data from token with the help of user keyProrperty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you may be looking for ancestor queries, that according to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries#ancestor), look like this:

As the example in the docs shows:

```
purchases = Purchase.query(
    Purchase.customer == customer_entity.key).fetch()
```

This applied to your use case will be then something like:

```
class Token(EndpointsModel):
    user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User) #added kind User in key property, just in case
    token = ndb.StringProperty()

    @classmethod
    def get_by_user(cls, key):
        return   cls.query(cls.token == key).fetch()

###Fetching data 
data = User.get_by_name('jaskaran')

##HERE WILL BE GOOD TO PRINT DATA.KEY, FOR EXAMPLE,
##TO MAKE SURE THAT YOU ARE ACTUALLY RETRIEVING SOMETHING
print(data.key)

print(Token.get_by_user(data.key)
```

As a side note, the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries#filter_by_prop) also explain that `Account.get_by_id(...) is faster than Account.query(...).get()`, therefore removing the .get() will be a good update to the code.